# What's the difference between std::endl and '\n'

Tags: c++, linux, iostream, endl

I've read the difference between `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `std::endl` flushes the buffer and `'\n'` doesn't. However, as far as I know `stdout` on linux is line-buffered anyway, so does it mean that `std::cout << ... << std::endl` is the same as `std::cout << ... << '\n'`?

Comment: _However, as far as I know stdout on linux is line-buffered anyway_ Only if `stdout` is writing to a device.  If it's redirected to a file, then it's block-buffered.

Comment: and the buffering mode can be changed easily with [setvbuf()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf)

Comment: There is no need to say "basically". You are not presenting a summary of the difference; that *is* the difference. You can check [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl); the cppreference documentaion starts by stating that `std::cout << std::endl` is the same as `std::cout << '\n';` followed by `std::cout.flush();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
std::ostream os;

os << std::endl; // more concise

os << '\n' << std::flush; // more explicit about flushing
```

Those two lines have the exact same effect.

The manual flushing is often a waste of time:

- If the output stream is line-buffered, which should be the case for `std::cout` if it connects to an interactive terminal *and* the implementation can detect that, then printing `\n` already flushes.
- If the output stream is paired with an input stream you read from directly afterwards (`std::cout` and `std::cin` are paired), then reading already flushes.
- If you nobody waits for the data to arrive at its destination, flushing is again just going to waste.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::endl` - it says exactly what you want: And end-line symbol.
There is little reason to stick with archaic character-codes when you have so much more expressive and easier to use methods.

Does it print a different character? No. `std::endl` is expanded to `\n` which is then expanded to the system newline symbol (the correct form is `\r\n` - even Unix-Terminals in their raw data are converting `\n` to `\r\n` cause `\n` really only means "go down 1 line" and NOT "Got to the start of the next line". Only Unix-derived OSes use `\n` )

Is there a performance difference? It depends:
When using an shell then no - `\n` flushes just the same (unless you specifically change the stream-settings to not synchronise output with printf ).
When doing file-IO: Yes - here `\n` does not flush. So if you are fine with uncompleted writes then you can use `\n`

But the performance-difference is mostly irrelevant. You are talking about text output here.... Specially when it is for user-interfaces this is completely negligible as no human will read hundreds of lines every second for the flushing to have any noticeable impact.

Comment: This is incorrect in several ways. `std::endl` is more than an end of line symbol. The end-of-line symbol is `\n`.  `std::endl` outputs this (using `stream.put( '\n' )`), and then flushes the stream (which just outputting a `'\n'` doesn't do). And `'\n'`, regardless of how it is output, is converted to the native end of line: a single 0x0A on Unix machines, and the two byte sequence 0x0D, 0x0A on Windows (and a single 0x0D on older Macs.) And while the performance difference probably isn't relevant when outputting to a terminal, it definitely can be when outputting to a file.

Comment: "is more than an end of line symbol." No. It prints exactly the same symbol. That it is flushing does not change the fact that the resulting output is by definition the same thing. I also mentioned that `endl` will flush, just added that `\n` ALSO WILL FLUSH given an interactive shell.
So which parts exactly are incorrect - specially as you claim there are several.

Comment: And "it definitely can be when outputting to a file." will have to strongly disagree there. In most situations were people ask that is simply not the case.
If you are writing tens of thousands of short lines - as in lines shorter than ~100 characters then sure. There it is noticeable. But how often does that realistically happen, specially from people that don't know what a buffered stream and its implications are.
To go further - the behaviour of file-IO is rather different between compilers and platforms ( some are auto-flushed anyways)

Comment: `std::endl` is more than an end of line symbol, because it also flushes the stream, which `'\n'` doesn't. And C++ doesn't have any concept of line buffering, although having `std::cout` tied to `stdout` may make it seem so in some cases. Finally, while I would generally recommend using `std::endl`, rather than `'\n'`, it *can* make a performance difference. It won't always, and for a lot of small programs, it certainly won't make a difference, but it can, and an experienced programmer will be aware of this.

Answer (score -2):

This `std::cout << ... << std::endl` and this `std::cout << ... << '\n'` are not exactly the same. In the last one, the newline `\n` is streamed to the output. In most cases this will be interpreted by a console as a newline. But `std::endl` means (as you already mentioned) exactly flush and newline in the output console.

Assume you would write this in a document. In Linux the `\n` is sufficient. But Windows expects `\r\n`. So the new lines will not occur using `\n` and e.g. Notepad++ in Windows.

Comment: `os << std::endl;` is exactly the same as `os << '\n' << std::flush;`. It doesn't output some magical newline, but also \n. Whether the output stream is in text mode, and on a system that translates \n to \r\n or not is a different affair.

Comment: "But Windows expects `\r\n`." -- I believe the console uses text mode by default, which means that on Windows, programs can ignore the fact that Windows internally uses `\r\n` as line breaks, so that programs can simply use `\n`. This is translated automatically to `\r\n` when appropriate (and vice versa).

Comment: So if I 1)use linux; 2) print to stdout(no redirection); 3)haven't changed buffering mode, they are equal?

Comment: @Deduplicator Maybe I expressed it in a missleading way. My intention is to state, that `std::cout << ... << std::endl` is not the same as `std::cout << ... << "\n"`. As you already mentioned, there is no magical newline. I am not sure if it will always be `\n` or `\r\n` in Windows. So I wanted to state that the user can trust on it, that `std::endl` will create a newline and flush the output -tream in the output console of the operating system.

Comment: `'\n'` tells the steam to do whatever is necessary to produce a new line. That hides system dependencies: it doesn't matter what the convention is on the OS that the code has been compiled for; the stream will get it right.

Comment: @PeteBecker So it is a runtime-thing how the "\n" is interpreted and not a decision made at compiletime?

Comment: The runtimes library handles `'\n'`; when you build an application you link to the runtime library. So in a sense, it's a compile-time decision, because that's when the application gets linked; in another sense, its a runtime decision, because the character `'\n'` just gets passed to the stream code, and the stream code does whatever is appropriate.