# Unable to pass function pointer as function param

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I would like to pass function pointer as a function parameter.

Here is my code:

```
void AuthServerOpcodes::ValidateAndSetServerOpcode(ServerOpcode serverOpcode, void(*handlerFunc(std::vector<std::byte> data))) {}
```

Here is the function I would like to pass as second parameter in `ValidateAndSetServerOpcode`:

```
void AuthServerOpcodes::Test(std::vector<std::byte> data) {
    std::cout << "all good" << std:end
}
```

Here is how I try to pass it:

```
ValidateAndSetServerOpcode(SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST, &Test);
```

However this seems to be not the correct way. When I try to do it in that way I get error:

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void (*(*) 
(std::vector<std::byte>))' with an rvalue of type 'void 
(AuthServerOpcodes::*)(std::vector<std::byte>)': different return type 
('void (*)' vs 'void')
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `void(*handlerFunc)(std::vector<std::byte> data)`?

Comment: @NutCracker No.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a member function with bare function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149407/call-a-member-function-with-bare-function-pointer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers to member must be qualified with the class type, so you need to get the pointer you'll need to use

```
ValidateAndSetServerOpcode(SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST, &AuthServerOpcodes::Test);
```

But it looks like you've tried that in the previous edit, so I guess you've called the function pointer to member incorrectly. You didn't show a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can't help you more, please create one. Anyway I've created a [compiled example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMRABmAGykADqgWE6rR6hiaCfgFqdDZ2jkYubu6cisqYqkEMBMzEBCHGpuZKKlG0mdkEMQ7Orh7eClk5eWHJ9eWVcQkenACUiqgGxMgcAORS7rbIhlgA1OLuOgBuaUTEc9jiAAwAgmMTU5iz88j16FhUa5s7kuO0kwYzczrq9cSYzEYX25cvBqrTWwYCAgGK4lsQAPI%2BNBYBSXcQAdlk22mKOmBAAnj5MGdpgtUHh0NMIACgSDiGDIdDMAoQCAAFQACRE6HYxAAYgZbt0ICdaUtVCRHryQE50QRMGtZpJPN05kidsjUXiCdMAGpsAnMcVbbQgxig1yUjCYCAAejp0zJFKhxumSnJhptWFI0zppsuqM9XqZ2lZHNu0wQzL9nOQsvc8s9ysJABVqQQeQR0HzloL5sLReLJVJPOgtcxw5GlfjCQAlTkQQtw%2BEAETlcO20f%2BgOBBohTuptPVrE12t1mH1DvbVLNFqtjqpdrbRudrvdiq90x9LNc/uQgeDq9Dsq%2BiI9qOF/JWQqTtMzEvc2GmRnRqtTqwj%2B5RECBeAUAFo1nSg76t1yIDed4CsQhaoqaprTCwrCsGiCAHD%2BWCrLudZfI2JbNqS04djSIBxvUibJiAR5pjoGZiheV45nmWTdLMe4Lnap4oP0BCHDojxSpIbAwcAqAYOIACsOi0FIkj1shDZbE2JKtkOM6diA5a0JW1ZFii3a9pgOroHq47Dsao6WgAsgwADiAD6VjgqZACS9jmaW2AAIoAKrYAwMYum6UqeDJenyTheEEFWEmoVJ6Fsq8mBlNotjAGuJTEi2/nYTm0yoFCpBPhhsnWlSOHLiGAYIUVyBZQxh73iehHntm0rUQWqnZRAGXIAAdN%2Bm7stuEANSFOy1pcwy9KwIDDAJwykKYwwbJNqBjexMhyHa/SDAcYycJNBBjbN3S9AA1iAAkCW17jwud3AABzwldGwAJzcHd7hCGN3CTUYXAbBsU07XNY2TTS33bTNw2kHAsAwIgzFGD4eCsuQlBoDDcM1MAnAbOYVBw%2BKxA0hATi/aQTi2Nk6JjZtpBI0YWgEOCtCsGTIOkFgRgiMA7CE/grzpEsNJM5gAAeaSAiMFO2OKo1Mz2TjEKTehYOTW3EHgH3DJtvQ0PQTBsBwPD8B4QhsygchyEIeBODSkC9BlJR8%2B%2B4KSNM74nHMNYSEtMicPCAOpOkGgQJYTSmMkljtNUbjJBEgR0EH4T%2BNHtBh/ENQtL7JRlI0%2Bj5IIRTLBkDQVLYVTJxHigF7HLQF0nnQ9H0AxDFwI1jRNP1M/NwwC5dnjvp43DTMAyDrujbWOxAuCECQUpJC6ejI6yU/uLRi2yDIW2/XtpBwcwiGUAdIDcNwbWeJIJ8CZwkhn3dGwCRsl0vcMb2kB9N%2Bt7NpDtwDIBA%2BvYOQxASAsR8ICBGEAkaw1ZAbbEE9S6a0YFBXWvAADussfCKybuNSa0037tzGO4aYiDCAIGmJ3buvd%2B6D2mMPSQa8QYby3jvSs99H7P2%2Blgv6wxP7f1oXvA%2BR8T4X3Ppfa%2Bt977uEwYTD%2BpBga7XQdQ1%2B7CaEyNIGCAIGhuBAA) on Compiler Explorer

```
typedef void (AuthServerOpcodes::*HandlerFunc)(std::vector<std::byte> &);

void AuthServerOpcodes::ValidateAndSetServerOpcode(ServerOpcode serverOpcode,
        HandlerFunc handlerFunc)
{
    std::vector<std::byte> myVector;
    (this->*handlerFunc)(myVector);   // call the hander
}

void FreeStandingFunction(AuthServerOpcodes& opc,
    AuthServerOpcodes::HandlerFunc handlerFunc,
    std::vector<std::byte> &data)
{
    (opc.*handlerFunc)(data);
}
```

As you can see the pointer to member must be called with `->*` or `.*` and the whole dereferencing must be wrapped inside `()` because those operators has lower precedence than the function call operator `()`

See also [Function pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2402579/995714)

Some off-topic note:

- Don't use lines that are too long like that
- Don't pass vectors by values unless you really need to preserve the outside value. Always pass by reference with `const std::vector<>&` (or remove `const` to modify the outside variable)
- [Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64253865/995714)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

There is no function pointer to that function, because it is a *member* function.

You can instead pass a pointer-to-member-function, or better yet a `std::function` bound to a lambda that captures the `this` pointer.

Comment: So I can pass pointer to functions in same class or as well as parent class functions ?

Comment: What about friend classes ?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWigns I have updated my question with the suggested by you changes to call member function but it still does not work.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWigns can you please make an example about `std::function` so the answer may be complete and I can accept it?

Comment: You can trivially find one yourself with ten seconds of research.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a type mismatch, your function is a method of the AccountManager class,
so it has this signature similar to:
`static void Login(AccountManager *this, std::vector<..> data);`

You can either detach function from class, change your type definition of `handlerFunc` or consider different techniques like `std::mem_fn` or `std:bind`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So If I create a function in `AuthServerOpcodes` I can pass it instead? Can you make an example with `std::bind` ?